# Exceptions- incorrect behaviour in VC++2015 CTP Ultimate

Tags: c++, exception

I have a program:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    void func()
    {
        cout << "Inside func" << endl;
        throw;
    }
};

int myfunc()
{
    Test T;
    T.func();
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    myfunc();
    cout << "Main func" << endl;//should not print
    getchar();
}
```

My expectation was this program would terminate from `main`, but on VC++ 2015 the `main` `cout` was getting printed. Which was against my understanding , so I compiled it with `gcc` and it works fine there.

Is this a bug in VC++ 2015 or the behaviour of program termination like this is unspecified/UB behaviour? Should it ever execute `cout << "Main func" << endl;`?

IDE: VS2015 CTP Ultimate Preview(for 30 days)

flags: `/GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /fp:precise /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\exception.pch"`

Comment: Could you provide the compiler flags used for compilation, please?

Comment: What happens if you use the final version of VS2015? CTP is quite old, between RTM and CTP there was also a RC.

Comment: @namezero: Where do I find it? Anyway I have not changed default settings as well.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: This is what I downloaded from microsoft website 1 month back. Still they are providing this.

Comment: @InQusitive: under Project Settings->C/C++->Command Line.

Comment: @namezero: updated in the question.

Comment: Do your run your program under debugger? Same behavior on VS2013 community with debugger attached, however works fine (calls abort) without.

Comment: So you *are* building release? Because in simon's answer you comment inferred you weren't before.

Comment: @namezero I started with debugger mode and my post is regarding that. That time I hadn't tried with release mode until simon posted his answer.

Comment: Could you post the flags with which the behavior of the question is observed? Possibly try with `/O1` instead of `/O2`, and try to leave out `/Oi`. Just wondering if the compiler is smart enough to infer something about your program. Either way, have you tried with the latest VS2015 version as suggested?

Comment: @namezero Earlier I had posted incorrect flags, but now it is the latest.

Comment: [Visual Studio 2015 was released](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) a week ago. And it shows expected behavior. No need to use pre-release versions anymore ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`throw` without an argument, when called in improper context, should call `terminate`.

According to the standard:

> A *throw-expression* with no operand rethrows the currently handled exception
>
> ....
>
> If no exception is presently being handled, executing a *throw-expression* with no operand calls `std::terminate()`

Then the behavior depends on currently installed `std::terminate_handler`, but anyway the execution is supposed to be terminated.

> *Required behavior*: A `terminate_handler` shall terminate execution of the program without returning
>   to the caller.
>
> *Default behavior*: The implementation’s default `terminate_handler` calls `abort`.
>    The default implementation calls `std::abort`.

Comment: Looks a bit strange. Do you have a custom `terminate_handler`?

Comment: Nope, I just have this code, no other modification.

Comment: Given that the example didn't install one and abort() apparently isn't called, it seems to be. But I am reluctant to say that something that basic is broken.

Comment: @InQusitive BTW, I cannot reproduce it with my VS 2015 (14.0.23107.0). The application terminates as expected.

Comment: under debugger mode? Your build is latest than mine.

Comment: @InQusitive Yes, under debugger too.

Comment: Interesting thing however is that in VS 2015 release (14.0.23107) debugger breaks at problematic line, but you can still continue execution by pressing "Continue" button. In this case `terminate` is not being called, "Main func" is printed and you can even press enter and finish program with status 0. Without debugger attached you cannot do this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are running your test program in VS debug environment. Try compile your program in release build and run it by click on the executable. The exception error box will pop and the "Main func" would not be printed.
In fact, the behavior in VS debugger is a feature rather than a bug.

Microsoft states [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/01/08/understanding-exceptions-while-debugging-with-visual-studio.aspx) that:

> In Visual Studio, when exceptions are thrown or end up unhandled, the
>   debugger can help you debug these by breaking just like it breaks when
>   a breakpoint is hit.

At that point the developer can troubleshoot what goes wrong, or continue the execution which will lead to the behavior the poster see, i.e. the printing of the `main func` in his question.

Comment: A debug build should suffice, too (observable behavior argument). With a debugger attached, a breakpoint is usually triggered in abort().

Comment: @namezero: When I change into release mode, it gives expected behaviour.

Comment: I did test with the way I posted before I posted. The debugger is behave different as the release executable. The debugger allows the print of the "Main func", but the release executable does not.

Comment: So I've got a down vote by trying to explain the VS behavior I observed?

Comment: @simon Wasn't me. However, if the behavior changes between debug and release builds, that sets of alarm bells. Can you post the assembly around the `throw;` for both? I don't have VS2015.

Comment: @namezero: I guess I am not going to post the assembly you requested. See my edited answer above. I understand it is not you. I really don't understand why this is downvoted, sigh.